# Getting no response from the server when sending market orders via the FIX API

Tags: python, fix-protocol

I am trying to send a purchase order, but I am not receiving a response from the server. The session is correct, and I am connected to port 5202. The python code is:

```
      mdr = fix.Message()

      mdr.getHeader().setField(fix.BeginString(fix.BeginString_FIX44))
      mdr.getHeader().setField(fix.MsgType(fix.MsgType_NewOrderSingle))
      mdr.getHeader().setField(fix.TargetSubID('TRADE'))
      mdr.getHeader().setField(fix.SenderSubID('TRADE'))
      mdr.setField(fix.ClOrdID(str(str(self.genExecID())))
      mdr.setField(fix.HandlInst('1')))
      mdr.setField(fix.Side('1'))
      mdr.setField(fix.Symbol('1'))
      mdr.setField(fix.OrderQty(0.01))
      mdr.setField(fix.Currency('EUR'))
      mdr.setField(fix.TimeInForce('1'))
      mdr.setField(fix.OrdType('1'))
      trstime = fix.TransactTime()
      trstime.setString(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
      mdr.setField(trstime)
      fix.Session.sendToTarget(mdr, self.sessionID)
```

And the message it generates is:

```
8=FIX.4.4☺9=158☺35=D☺34=2☺49=demo.ctrader.3449248☺50=TRADE☺52=20220310-10:37:36.000☺56=CSERVER☺57=TRADE☺11=1☺15=EUR☺21=1☺38=0.01☺40=1☺54=1☺55=1☺59=1☺60=20220310-10:37:36.898☺10=130☺
```

Does anyone miss any fields or see any errors in the message. Thank you very much.

Comment: Best thing probably is to ask the counter party that you connect to. They should be able to help you.

Comment: Hello, I have already tried. They refer me to an application of theirs on github.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late...but I had a similar issue and changed my fix message to the following:

1. Tag 50 (sendersubid) - Should be a random string of characters for that particular session you are logging in with and should be changed with every new login. If you log in multiple times with the same sendersubid, I think the server rejects.
2. Tag 38 (lot size) - you used "0.01". Try instead "1000"
3. "CSERVER" should be "cServer"

hope it helps